# How do I stop blocking my Flask Route with an Async call?

Tags: python, asynchronous, flask, python-3.4

I have a function, which creates a new inventory item AND calls an external API to generate a bar code. How can I call,  `urllib.request.urlretrieve(api_request_url, file_name)` AFTER my function returns so that it does not block my API?

```
@api.route('/api/inventory/new/<id>', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def new_inventory(id):
    name=request.json['name']
    uid=request.json['uid']
    item = Inventory(common_name=name, uid=uid)
    api_request_url = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data={0}".format(uid)
    file_name = "app/static/{0}.png".format(uid)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(api_request_url, file_name)
    db.session.add(item)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({'results': True})
```

Comment: Spawning a new, short-lived thread would be one of many ways. But the much more important question is: How would you deal with error handling? Are you really ok with your API already returning "OK", indicating a new item has been created, if it's not clear yet that the QR code generation will succeed?

Comment: A problem for another day, I'm curious how one would create a new thread or make an async call today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply putting Flask in a WSGI container such as [Gunicorn or uWSGI](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/wsgi-standalone/) would prevent blocking the API.  Creating a thread would be a second level of optimization, and finally for production you'd want to implement a task queue with something like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org).